# Java concurrent Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to setup a small printing program.
I have this code that a student tries to print a document if the printer paper level is higher then the number of pages the student wants to print. 
At the moment the student cannot print the document because the paper level is less then the number of pages needed to print. At this point the printDocument() must wait for a notify() from the method refilPaper();
How can I do this?

Main Code:

```
class classA
{
   public static void main ( String args[] )
   {
    // TODO code application logic here
        LaserPrinter printer = new LaserPrinter("MyPrinter", 1, 30, 50, 0);
        ThreadGroup students = new ThreadGroup("Students");
        ThreadGroup technicians = new ThreadGroup("Technicians");

        Student student1 = new Student(students, "User 1", printer);
        PaperTechnician paperTech1 = new PaperTechnician(technicians, "PaperTechnician1", printer);

        student1.start();
        paperTech1.start();

      while(true)
         {
             try
             {    student1.join();
                  paperTech1.join();
              }
             catch(InterruptedException ex){}
         }
   }
}
```

Printer Code:

```
private boolean available = false;

@Override
public synchronized void printDocument(Document document) {

    while(getPrinter_CurrentPaperLevel() <= document.getNumberOfPages() || getPrinter_ToonerLevel() <= document.getNumberOfPages())
    {
        try { 
             System.out.println("waiting for refill of something..");
             wait();
             } catch(InterruptedException e){ }
    }
    available = false;
    notifyAll(); 
    System.out.println(document);

}

public synchronized void refilPaper(){
   while ( available )
     {
     try {
         System.out.println("Not available");
         wait();
         } catch(InterruptedException e){ }
     }
     setPrinter_CurrentPaperLevel(ServicePrinter.SheetsPerPack);
     available = true;
     notifyAll();

}
```

Any help would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: @LigamentThrasher When I am running the program because there is less paper in the printer it gets stuck in: "Waiting for refill.." How can I make the refill paper method to refill and notify the print document method: "ok, now you can print"

Comment: Also, when you get to asking your question, I'm pretty sure we'll need the `Student` and `PaperTechnician` relevant code.

Comment: Otonel please add that to the question. Why don't you help us help you? If you give as many details as possible it'll be easier for all of us.

Comment: As @LigamentThrasher commented, you have not identified what the problem is. You have also not posted all your code. And, finally, if this is homework, would you instructor approve of you posting this?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Paper technician has a method run() - laserPrinter.refilPeper(); and student creates a new document object and: printer1.printDocument( documentObject ) ;

Comment: @LigamentThrasher It is just a general question on Java multithreading not the whole homework.

Comment: @Otonel So what? Why don't you improve your question and make it clear for everyone? Comments are much harder to notice and read.

Comment: did you call "refilPaper" ??

Comment: @Antoniossss PapperTechnician extends Thread, it has a method run(){laser printer.refilPeper();} I am starting the PaperTechnician thread in main.

Comment: show us the Technicial code

Comment: @Antoniossss https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GuX-Og0FI9lm-1Iz31DNbnKITKQafoLd-9HUJvrJMoU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Antoniossss Any Idea?

Comment: Probably student and thecpnician are waiting for eachoter. Check for deadlocks

Comment: `while ( available )` is obviously not the right waiting condition considering the program logic and especially as you print out `"Not available"` in the loop. So use `while ( ! available )`…